# Salesforce Napili Community:How to give background color to the whole HTML body section?

Tags: community, css, html, napili, html-area-component

I am using the standard out of the box HTML Editor component but I am not able to give background color to the HTML text. The Code I used is:

```
h3 {
    background-color: green;
}

<div id="body" bgcolor="black">

    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <h3 style="color:red;" align="Center" size="10px" >Heading 1</h1>
    <p style="color:black;" align="Center" size="11px" bgcolor="red">First paragraph </p>
    <h3 style="color:red;" align="Center" size="10px">Heading 2.</h1>
    <p style="color:black;" align="Center" size="11px">Paragraph 2</p>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

The preview looked like this:

[image]

I would also like to know if there is a way to add background color to the entire section including the area with no text.

Comment: `\`` is the formatting character, not `'`, but its meant for inline code, ie, a single line of code. For blocks of code, highlight your code, then click the `{}` icon to indent it four spaces & render it as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you are trying to add CSS is kinda flawed. You have to define the CSS tags in style attribute for them to work.

[image: Colours working]

You can use Inline Styles Like I did. As you cannot use `**<Style>**` tag in HTML section.

```
 <div id="body2" style="background-color: green;">

    <br><br><br><br><br>
    <h3 style="color:red;" align="Center" size="10px" >Heading 1</h1>
    <p style="color:black;" align="Center" size="11px" bgcolor="red">First paragraph </p>
    <h3 style="color:red;" align="Center" size="10px">Heading 2.</h1>
    <p style="color:black;" align="Center" size="11px">Paragraph 2</p>
    <br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
</div>
```

Or in Community builder you have to edit the Theme->DropDown->Edit CSS, It will update the whole Community's CSS.(Can be a bit messy).